# Listview custom item control alignment

Tags: android

This is my custom item of a ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listicon_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listicon_imageview"
        android:text="This is my long text that should wrap appropriately and not overlay controls"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listicon_imageview"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_favorite_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_offered_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This code will produce this list item:

[image]

As one can see, the small text overlays the checkbox control. However, I want textview2 to display the ellipsize dots BEFORE the checkbox so that the checkbox is not overlaid like that. How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: Could you comment out the `android:ellipsise` and re-try?

Comment: use the `leftof "check_offered_list" in textview2` , hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/check_favorite_list"` in the TextView2. This statement align the textview2 to left of the checkBox (without overlaid).

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: What about other text view?

Answer (score -1):

use this one.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Speisopfer (10.02.2014)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="This is my long text that should wrap appropriately and not overlay controls. sdfsd dsf sdfds ds "
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_favorite_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_offered_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:enabled="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hoping, it will solve your issue.